# Is there an alternative to "dnsmasq"?

Tags: linux, dnsmasq

What is the recommended alternative to dnsmasq?  I am looking at overriding/configuring the TTL.

(Probably the only thing I miss from Windows is the fact that it was more aggressive in caching DNS responses than Linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "recommended alternative" to dnsmasq that I'm aware of.  Dnsmasq works perfectly fine for it's purpose.  You can set the TTL of local responses from a dnsmasq server with the `local-ttl` option.

I don't know of any technical basis for the claim that "Windows is [...] more aggressive in caching DNS responses than Linux" -- as far as I know, both operating systems respect the TTL provided to them.  Any attempt to do otherwise is severely broken.  The only possibility I can think of is that you are attempting to state that most Linux distributions don't pre-install a caching DNS resolver -- which is true, but ultimately irrelevant.  If you do not have a suitable caching resolver on your local network, you can install one of your choosing.  I use dnscache, from djbdns, which works wonderfully.